# J2EE link item from search result

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm developing a commercial site (like Ebay, it is for university project) and I made a search function, who show the list of items related to search key (it is working good for now). The problem is that in mvc pattern, for web applications, data should be managed by servlets and showed by jsp. I could link results to a servlet that load items by a stateles session bean, insert it into hHttpSession and redirect the user at the jsp (who get item information from HttpSession). 
The problem is that, if I develop it in this way, the item could not be retrieved by a direct link and it's not what I like (at least for items show). 
I would like to know if there is another way to implement it (by avoiding the direct access from jsp to stateless session bean), maybe like http://siteroot/web/item/itemcode where itemcode is something to recognize the correct item to load.

Answer (score 0):

I founded a way to do it. The solution i found is not as i wish (http://siteroot/web/item/itemcode) but it is functionally for my requests.

Following MVC pattern requirements, i attached a link to items (result from the search page) like http://siteroot/web/ShowItem?id=xxxxxxxxx wich is a simple servlet, that:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String temp = request.getParameter("id");
    Vendita v = retriever.getSell(temp);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("oggetto", v);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/excluded/showItem.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

wich show the item using showItem.jsp without changing the URL in the browser (so the item could be retrieved by direct link)